# asp.net - Manipulate Page Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if anyone could explain how to manipulate content for various sections of a page depending on if a button is clicked. I think what I am looking for is similar to an include in php. I wasnt sure if asp.net had a way to do the same (partial view?) or if bootstrap/jquery is the way to go. I've included a .png to illustrate what I am trying to do.

I would like section b's content to change based on what button is selected in section A. While not necessarily relevant to this question.. I then would like various user inputs in section B to manipulate existing content in section C.

[image]

Comment: there are lots of tutorials on partial views - which is what you're asking about in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, have an action that returns a `PartialView`:

```
public PartialViewResult MyPartial(string someText)
{
    var model = new MyPartialModel {SomeStuff = someText};
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Create the model and partial view as you would any other:

```
public class MyPartialModel
{
    public string SomeStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model ExampleApp.Models.MyPartialModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeStuff)
```

Then on your page you can load in your partial via ajax with jQuery:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="load-partial">Load The Partial!</button>
</div>

<div id="section-b"></div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#load-partial').click(function () {
                $.get('MyPartial', { sometext: "Hello!" }).done(function (data) {
                    $('#section-b').html(data);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

**Edit to answer comment:**
If you don't want to instantiate a new model in the controller each time, you can pass the model (more or less) directly from the view.
In you controller, have a very simple action that accepts a model as a parameter and returns the partial view. Note the `HttpPost` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult MyPartial(MyPartialModel model)
{          
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

The model's got more than one property this time:

```
public class MyPartialModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The partial's pretty much the same, except it now displays the new properties of the model.

```
@model MVCPlayGround.Models.MyPartialModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
```

The jquery on the main page/view is very also similar, but uses POST instead of GET.

```
// these could be anything, from control on the page, or whatever
var name = "James";
var age = 30;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#load-partial').click(function () {
        // note that Name and the Age are the names of the properties in our model
        $.post('MyPartial', { Name: name, Age: age }).done(function (data) {
            $('#section-b').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This works because when data transmitted via POST, it's treated as form data, and when the controller's deciding which action to use it'll look at the parameters for the actions, and compare them to the form data available. The `MyPartialModel` contains properties that match the form data, so it chooses that action. There are other subtle rules, but that's basically it. Behind the scenes it'll still be instantiating a model in the controller, it's just in the framework, not in the code you've written.

**Another edit**

Having just re-read your comment I don't think I've answered it fully.
If you want to save the changes you've made in a partial view to the main view, have some hidden fields in the main view to hold this data.

```
<input type="hidden" id="name-holder" />
<input type="hidden" id="age-holder" />
```

And then when you want to store a value to them, just set the values with jquery:

```
$('#some-save-button-maybe').click(function(){
    $('#name-holder').val($('id-of-name-on-partial').val());
    $('#age-holder').val($('id-of-age-on-partial').val());
});
```

When you click on a the button to show a partial, send the appropriate data to the controller to render in the partial:

```
$('#load-partial').click(function () {
    $.post('MyPartial', { Name: $('#name-holder').val(), Age: $('#age-holder').val() }).done(function (data) {
        $('#section-b').html(data);
    });
});
```

Hopefully that's what you need...

Comment: Is there a way to go back and forth between partial views without having to create a new instance of the model each time? In other words, retain data stored in the model outside of the partial view? My first thought was to pass the model to the actual view and then consume it from the partials but that doesn't seem to be working out.. 

For example.. My model has several bools defaulting to true.  I want the user to be able to toggle those. Then move on to the next partial view. What i am seeing now is that if they return to the partial they already altered it returns to the defaults.

Comment: I'll make an edit which will hopefully help you out.

Comment: I just learned so much from your edits. Thank you for being thorough.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are partial views in MVC, and they are usually belong in the `Views/Shared` folder of your project and are prefixed with a `_` (i.e. `_MyPartial.cshtml`.

As @AdamHeeg pointed out in the comments, there are many tutorials on the web about this kind of setup and many different ways to achieve what you are after.

Here is roughly how I might tackle it...

HTML

```
<nav>
    @Html.ActionLink("Button 1", "GetSectionB")
</nav>

<section id="sectionB">
    <!-- Content here -->
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
$('nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get(this.href, function (html) {
        $('#sectionB').html(html);
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public PartialViewResult GetSectionB()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    //do stuff

    return PartialView("_SectionB", vm);
 }
```